# TLA+ spec stalls as CHOOSE does not select a previous selected value

Tags: tla+

As I am starting to get used to TLA+, I started by modelling the Knight Quest problem, in which a knight must eventually reach every possible square of the chess board. For that, I've used 2 different variables: the *current* position and *occupied* set of positions.

First, I started to define my *Init* and *Next* action predicates, along with my specification and fair specification (in the WF I've only used current, as occupied may in some cases stall due to the returning to a certain position; however, if I set the WF to both, the issue is the same).

```
CONSTANT N
VARIABLE occupied, current
vars    == << occupied, current >>
Possible == 0..N-1

Inv    == /\ Cardinality(occupied) \leq N^2
          /\ IsFiniteSet(occupied)
          /\ occupied \subseteq (Possible \X Possible)

Jumps(pair) == LET x == pair[1]
                   y == pair[2] 
                IN 
                ({<<x+2, y-1>>, <<x+2, y+1>>, <<x-2,y+1>>, <<x-2,y-1>>}
                    \cup
                 {<<x+1, y-2>>, <<x+1, y+2>>, <<x-1,y+2>>, <<x-1,y-2>>}
                ) 
                    \cap 
                (Possible \X Possible)

Init == \E x \in Possible     : \E y \in Possible : /\ occupied = {<<x,y>>}
                                                    /\ current  = <<x,y>>

Next == LET S == Jumps(current) 
            Chosen == CHOOSE s \in S: TRUE
        IN
            /\ current'  = Chosen
            /\ occupied' = occupied \cup {Chosen}

Spec      == Init /\ [][Next]_vars
FairSpec  == Spec /\ WF_occupied(Next)
```

Then I've set a invariant *NotSolved*, so TLC returns me the contraction of the invariant: in which, the occupied reaches the cardinality of (= (N-1)^2), meaning that every position was once occupied.
`NotSolved == Cardinality(occupied) < (N-1)^2`

However, as soon as it reaches a current position, where the CHOOSE has to select a position that once was chosen (return to the same position, to then select another), the spec stalls. Which means, that the cardinality of *occupied* is never the same as the chess board.

I am guessing CHOOSE is the actual problem, but I am not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, CHOOSE does something else than you expect. It is a function that returns an arbitrary value fulfilling the specified criteria. But because it's a function it always returns the *same* value for the same expression. After all you want

```
(CHOOSE s \in S : P(s)) = (CHOOSE s \in S : P(s))
```

to hold. Alternatives are usually expressed with logical disjunction ( for example `Action(0) \/ Action(1)` ) or the existential quantifier (for example `\E s \in S: P(s) /\ Action(s)` ). In your case you need to change `Next` to:

```
Next == LET S == Jumps(current) 
        IN \E Chosen \in S:
              /\ current'  = Chosen
              /\ occupied' = occupied \cup {Chosen}
```

When you check for `NotSolved` as an invariant you will get a trace that really exceeds your size limits.

Nevertheless, the current description does allow for a path where the same element of `S` is chosen over and over again. You can prevent that by adding `/\ ~(Chosen \in occupied)` as a conjunct. But that also means at some point you will have exhausted `S` and your algorithm will stall which you need to take into account.

Comment: CHOOSE even returns the same value for the same *and equivalent* expressions.

Comment: Just as an explanation: I realized my comment was not helpful so I had deleted it. Indeed, we expect the choice operator to be extensional in TLA+.